# Get max number of occurrences of duplicate values based on another column's value

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe, how can I get the max number of occurrences of one value (Sub ID) based on another column's value (ID)? For instance, let's take the following table as an example:

[image]

And this is the result I am expecting where Result stores the max number of occurrences of the same value from Sub ID based on ID:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of situation you can use a groupBy.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(15,size =(30,2)),columns= ["ID", "Sub ID"])

df.sort_values(by=["ID", "Sub ID"],
                             ignore_index =True,
                             ascending=True,
                             inplace=True)


df2 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Sub ID']).size().reset_index(name ='Total Amount')

print(df2)
```

Let me know